# Promise was created but not returned from it in knex

Tags: javascript, promise, knex.js

I have the following code. I wonder whatever how I set the return, it always show that I didnt return anything to the promise?

```
.get('/:lang/home', connectensurelogin.ensureLoggedIn("/index"), csrfProtection, function(req, res){

            _DB('user')
            .where({ 
                email: req.user.email,
                name: req.user.name
            })
            .then(function(result){
                if(result.length>0 && result[0].random == null){
                    return "null";
                }else{
                    return "existed";
                }
            })
            .then(function(data){
                res.render('home', {
                    classlist: "home " + data,
                    csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
                });
                return "ok";
            })
            .catch(function(){
                res.render('home', {
                    classlist: "home",
                    csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
                });
                return "err";
            })
            ;

})
```

I tried disable connectensurelogin and no more wanring.

Comment: What does `req.csrfToken()` do? Maybe it does create a promise?

Comment: @Bergi it simply creates a token, i think not related. Anyway, I just tried remove and the same warning exists.

Comment: Maybe you need to return Promise from the callback, ie. `return _DB('user')..where(...)....`.

Comment: Where exactly does the warning come from? Is it a linter warning or a runtime warning? Which promise library are you using, Bluebird? Does the warning contain a stacktrace?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Ah, that's a possibility, when there is a middleware that uses promises and then calls the framework (express.js?) callback. This should be fixed in the middleware though, not here. The callback does write to the `res`ponse, it doesn't need to `return` anything.

Comment: @Bergi, it was just a thought. The issue would be easier to penetrate with better understanding of the OP's " it always show that I didnt return anything to the promise", and as you say, linter or runtime?

Comment: You should try to write single file example code to reproduce your issue with some dummy query. The problem you are experiencing is not in the code you have shared.